# Finding unique values in multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to solve a [freeCodeCamp exercise](http://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/sorted-union#?solution=function%20unite%28arr1%2C%20arr2%2C%20arr3%29%20%7B%0A%20%20var%20everything%20%3D%20[]%3B%0A%20%20%2F%2Fconcat%20all%20arrays%20except%20the%20first%20one%0A%20%20for%28var%20x%20%3D%200%3B%20x%20%3C%20arguments.length%3B%20x%2B%2B%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20for%28var%20y%20%3D%200%3B%20y%20%3C%20arguments[x].length%3B%20y%2B%2B%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20everything.push%28arguments[x][y]%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%2F%2Ffunction%20that%20returns%20duplicates%0A%20%20function%20returnUnique%28arr%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20arr.reduce%28function%28dupes%2C%20val%2C%20i%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28arr.indexOf%28val%29%20!%3D%3D%20i%20%26%26%20dupes.indexOf%28val%29%20%3D%3D%3D%20-1%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dupes.push%28val%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20dupes%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20[]%29%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20var%20dupes%20%3D%20returnUnique%28everything%29%3B%0A%20%20%0A%20%20for%28var%20n%20%3D%201%3B%20n%20%3C%20arguments.length%3B%20n%2B%2B%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20for%28var%20m%20%3D%200%3B%20m%20%3C%20dupes.length%3B%20m%2B%2B%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%28arguments[n].hasOwnProperty%28dupes[m]%29%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20arguments[n].splice%28arguments[n].indexOf%28dupes[m]%29%2C%201%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20return%20arr1.concat%28arr2%29.concat%28arr3%29%3B%0A%20%20%0A%7D%20%20%0A%0Aunite%28[1%2C%203%2C%202]%2C%20[5%2C%202%2C%201%2C%204]%2C%20[2%2C%201]%29%3B%0A) with this goal:

> Write a function that takes two or more arrays and returns a new array
>   of unique values in the order of the original provided arrays.
>
> In other words, all values present from all arrays should be included
>   in their original order, but with no duplicates in the final array.
>
> The unique numbers should be sorted by their original order, but the
>   final array should not be sorted in numerical order.

So what I do is concatenate all the arguments into a single array called `everything`. I then search the array for duplicates, then search the arguments for these duplicates and `.splice()` them out.

So far everything works as expected, but the last number of the last argument does not get removed and I can't really figure out why.

Can anybody please point out what I'm doing wrong? Please keep in mind that I'm trying to learn, so obvious things probably won't be obvious to me and need to be pointed out. Thanks in advance.

```js
function unite(arr1, arr2, arr3) {
  var everything = [];
  //concat all arrays except the first one
  for(var x = 0; x < arguments.length; x++) {
    for(var y = 0; y < arguments[x].length; y++) {
      everything.push(arguments[x][y]);
    }
  }
  
  //function that returns duplicates
  function returnUnique(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(dupes, val, i) {
      if (arr.indexOf(val) !== i && dupes.indexOf(val) === -1) {
        dupes.push(val);
      }
      return dupes;
    }, []);
  }
  
  //return duplicates
  var dupes = returnUnique(everything);
  
  //remove duplicates from all arguments except the first one
  for(var n = 1; n < arguments.length; n++) {
    for(var m = 0; m < dupes.length; m++) {
      if(arguments[n].hasOwnProperty(dupes[m])) {
        arguments[n].splice(arguments[n].indexOf(dupes[m]), 1);
      }
    }
  }
  
  //return concatenation of the reduced arguments
  return arr1.concat(arr2).concat(arr3);
  
}  

//this returns [1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 2]
unite([1, 3, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you overcomplicated it a bit ;)

```js
function unite() {
    return [].concat.apply([], arguments).filter(function(elem, index, self) {
        return self.indexOf(elem) === index;
    });
}


res = unite([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1], [6, 7, 8]);
document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(res));
```

### Explanations

We split the problem into two steps:

- combine arguments into one big array
- remove non-unique elements from this big array

This part handles the first step:

```
[].concat.apply([], arguments)
```

The built-in method `someArray.concat(array1, array2 etc)` appends given arrays to the target. For example,

```
[1,2,3].concat([4,5],[6],[7,8]) == [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

If our function had fixed arguments, we could call `concat` directly:

```
function unite(array1, array2, array3) {
    var combined = [].concat(array1, array2, array3);
    // or
    var combined = array1.concat(array2, array3);
```

but as we don't know how many args we're going to receive, we have to use `apply`.

```
 someFunction.apply(thisObject, [arg1, arg2, etc])
```

is the same as

```
 thisObject.someFunction(arg1, arg2, etc)
```

so the above line

```
 var combined = [].concat(array1, array2, array3);
```

can be written as

```
 var combined = concat.apply([], [array1, array2, array3]);
```

or simply

```
 var combined = concat.apply([], arguments);
```

where `arguments` is a special array-like object that contains all function arguments (actual parameters).

Actually, last two lines are not going to work, because `concat` isn't a plain function, it's a method of `Array` objects and therefore a member of `Array.prototype` structure. We have to tell the JS engine where to find `concat`. We can use `Array.prototype` directly:

```
 var combined = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arguments);
```

or create a new, unrelated, array object and pull `concat` from there:

```
 var combined = [].concat.apply([], arguments);
```

This prototype method is slightly more efficient (since we're not creating a dummy object), but also more verbose.

Anyways, the first step is now complete. To eliminate duplicates, we use the following method:

```
 combined.filter(function(elem, index) {
     return combined.indexOf(elem) === index;
 })
```

For explanations and alternatives see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229821/989121).

Finally, we get rid of the temporary variable (`combined`) and chain "combine" and "dedupe" calls together:

```
return [].concat.apply([], arguments).filter(function(elem, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(elem) === index;
});
```

using the 3rd argument ("this array") of `filter` because we don't have a variable anymore.

Simple, isn't it? ;) Let us know if you have questions.

Finally, a small exercise if you're interested:

> Write `combine` and `dedupe` as separate functions. Create a function `compose` that takes two functions `a` and `b` and returns a new function that runs these functions in reverse order, so that `compose(a,b)(argument)` will be the same as `b(a(argument))`. Replace the above definition of `unite` with `unite = compose(combine, dedupe)` and make sure it works exactly the same.

Comment: would you mind commenting the code a bit, or at least explaining how it works :).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this :

```js
var Data = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1], [6, 7, 8]]

var UniqueValues = []

for (var i = 0; i < Data.length; i++) {
 UniqueValues = [...new Set(UniqueValues.concat(Data[i]))]
}

console.log(UniqueValues)
```

Comment: ...or simply `[...new Set(Data.flat())]`.